# On Rooting Desire HD

Tags: rooting, htc-desire-hd, s-off

I came across [this forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2221039) on rooting and getting S-OFF in HTC Desire HD.
In step 6 it says

> You should see the $ turn into a #. If this happens, congrats you have
>   root access.

and continues the steps. The question I have is, does the rooting process finish there or do I have to follow the other steps as well to get the phone rooted?

Comment: Have you asked your question over at "that forum post"? The one who posted it is obviously the best one to explain what he did.

Comment: @Izzy I narrowed down the question. Can you help me out now?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the `#` in the prompt, that means you've got root access. So I'd assume the process to be finished then.

Browsing the linket XDA thread: After this "step 6" comes a "big free space", indicationg something new is starting. And in fact, step 7+8 describe the *unlock* process for the bootloader. So yes, if you were just after root, you've got it at that point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I thought that unlocking the bootloader was step 1 of the guide. Is S-OFF necessary to flash a custom ROM on Desire HD? At [htcdev](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/about_unlock_process) it says that step 1 should be enough to flash a custom ROM. Maybe that doesn't apply to HTC DHD?

Comment: You're correct, I've mis-read that: Steps 7+8 are re-locking and flashing. As for S-Off (which stands for *Securebit Off*), see [Zuul's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/52096/16575), which already covers this ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### [Full HTC Desire HD (sense 3.0/android 2.3.5) guide to root, S-OFF/Sim Unlock](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2221039)

That guide is a step by step instruction to have your device with **root access**, **S-OFF** and **Sim Unlock**.
To achieve that you need to complete all the steps mentioned.

### Answer:

To have root access on your device, you can stop at the step you've mentioned.

If you want to flash your device, you will need to complete all the steps.

---

## [Better insights](http://www.pocketables.com/2013/04/why-you-want-root-and-s-off-on-htc-devices.html)

### What is root?

> Root, in the simplest terms, is the ability for an application to run with permissions that allow it to access everything.

### What is S-OFF?

> In simplest terms, S-OFF on HTC devices is the ability to flash unsigned code that modifies the kernel, boot, and radio partitions from recovery. Unsigned code is code that has not come from HTC directly, or has been modified in transit.
>
> Having S-OFF does not mean that you have root. Root is a function of a Superuser application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But at [htc dev it says](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/about_unlock_process) that unlocking the boot loader ([step 1 of the guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2221039)) is enough for flashing custom ROMs. So isn't that enough for me to install say [trickdorid](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/device/ace/developer/torxx?manifest=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.clockworkmod.com%2Fdeveloper%2Ftorxx%2Fmanifest&name=TrickDroid&deviceName=HTC%20Desire%20HD)?

Comment: **S-OFF** will give you full access to all partitions on your device. **root** will only give you full access and control over the basics... This is well explained both on the link I've provided and the link you've placed on the comment. :) Regarding the installation of _trickdorid_, I can't tell you for sure if **root** is enough, mainly because the link you've placed is broken ;)

Comment: The link is [this](http://trickdroid.org/category/desire-hd/), Would be really helpful if you can say if root is adequate.

Comment: Found the info [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1876566). Thanks for your help.